# onSubmit() vs isSubmitted() in Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

Sorry to ask this, but with previouse reading, re-reading of doc and all the changes I'm confused...
Which one is the preferred method to test a form `onSumbit()` or `isSubmitted()` ?

Comment: I have seen them in all the samples across agiletoolkit website

Comment: Providing a url to it would get you better answers.

Comment: for example this url has both methods     http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are essentially doing the same thing. isSubmitted() have been used in older versions of PHP, where closures were not easy to create.

```
if($form->isSubmitted()){
    ...
}
```

however with closures you can now create a function call-back like this:

```
$form->onSubmit(function($form){
    ...
});
```

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Basic.php#L401

One significant change though is that onSubmit() will [capture some exceptions](https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Basic.php#L370) and will automatically display them on the form. Therefore if your model has this

```
throw $this->exception('Wrong data','ForUser')->setField('name');
```

Then "name" field will be highlighted with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you' have two different things confused for each other.

`onSubmit()` is a native JavaScript event that is fired when a form is submitted and performs any actions you wish before the form is sent to the server (if it is even sent at all)

`isSubmitted()` looks like a custom function that is probably called when a form is submitted but is not native to JavaScript and may be part of the framework.

Comment: oh, sorry for the confusion, I'm talking about Agile Toolkit Framework.